# Java Filling an array with infinite variable names

Tags: java, arrays, enums

I have a project which requires me to have an array that stores two things for each entry:

1. the location of another entry in the array
2. A Boolean value

To do this I've considered making a new object which has a location and boolean method which would store each of the two things above. And then I would just need to open a 2D matrix of this type object.

Here lies my problem, the size of the 2D matrix must match that of a level file which could be as big as 300*300. I need a way in which I could create and name an object for each cell in the 2D matrix. The name doesn't matter because I will just refer to it as Object[n][n].location. Is there a way to do this? To make a large amount of objects with different names? Without having to do each one by hand.

I'm also open to other methods of solving this problem, this is just the solution I've thought up.

Comment: but you never mentioned about name property in your class for which you  will be creating matrix

Comment: You could have your program make up the names from a pattern. E.g. the X and Y coordinates separated by a comma.

Comment: @immibis I really like this idea, I'll give it a shot